# Is it possible to have a Heroku app I built be on the same domain as my Wordpress website?

Tags: django, wordpress, heroku, dns

I have a website hosted on Wordpress at domain [my domain name].com. I built an app using Django that is currently deployed on Heroku at [my domain name].herokuapp.com. The apps do not have conflicting routes. For example, the '/' route does not exist on the app I built myself. Is it possible to configure my DNS settings on Heroku such that I can use my custom domain name where a Wordpress website already lives?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking if both of your applications can live at the same domain.

The answer is yes....sort of.

## Subdomains

Your two sites would need to be on separate subdomains. For example your heroku app might have a CNAME record pointing to it like this

```
djangoapp.YOURDOMAIN.com.        CNAME  [my domain name].herokuapp.com.
```

I realize this might be confusing, but your django app would live at a prefix/subdomain.

Then the CNAME for your wordpress site might look like:

```
www.YOURDOMAIN.com.        CNAME  wordpress.com/YOURBLOG
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Not in the same domain.

Treas gave you a compromise but you understand that siteA.mydomain.com and siteB.mydomain.com are two different domains.

You CAN NOT have the following situation:

```
mydomain.com/    <- This goes to the wordpress site
mydomain.com/a   <- This one goes to the heroku site
mydomain.com/a/b <- But this one goes to the wordpress site
mydomain.com/c   <- and this one goes to the wordpress again.
```

You have a DNS configuration issue. It is not related to Heroku nor Wordpress. DNS can not be configured with routes. They can with sub-domains like trejas has described.